# SQLite - Phone Number Output

Tags: sqlite

I would like to amend the output of an phone number column in an existing SQLite DB.

From: +19995551212
To:  999-555-1212 OR (999) 555-1212

I was able to complete the first example.

```
sqlite>SELECT phonenumber,substr(phonenumber, 2, 1) || '-' || substr(phonenumber, 3, 3) || '-' || substr(phonenumber, 6, 3) || '-'  || substr(phonenumber, 9, 4) AS AmendedPhone from table;
```

Output:

```
phonenumber    AmendedPhone  
-------------  --------------

+12488601973   1-248-860-1973
```

But am stuck on the second example.  It appears to work, except for the first parenthesis of the area code.  All of my attempts yield a syntax error.  Is there an issue because I an using a parenthesis?

```
sqlite> SELECT phonenumber,substr(phonenumber, 3, 3) || ') ' || substr(phonenumber, 6, 3) || '-'  || substr(phonenumber, 9, 4) AS AmendedPhone from table;
```

Output:

```
phonenumber    AmendedPhone  
-------------  --------------

+12488601973   248) 860-1973
```

I realize that there any other more simple solutions in linux and Excel, but am trying to get this to work in SQLite.  Any suggestions or advice is appreciated.  TYIA

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying that gives a syntax error? Just adding a `'(' ||` in front of the rest works fine for me.

Comment: You are right...  That worked for me too.  Clearly I was overthinking.  Thanks!